# Выбрать всех пользователей с именем

Tags: php, laravel

Необходима помощь в правильной реализации API

Есть user model и lastName model

Которые связаны между собой ключами

И user имеет связь

```
public function lastName(){
    return $this->hasOne(LastName::class);
}
```

При выборе юзера и подключении этой связи я получаю следующий json

```
return User::with('lastName')->get();

    {
     "id": 1,
     "email": "imedhurst@example.org",
     "created_at": "2018-12-25 09:33:44",
     "updated_at": "2018-12-25 09:33:44",
     "last_name": {
          "id": 1,
          "user_id": 1,
          "title": "Pfannerstill",
          "language": "en",
          "created_at": "2018-12-25 09:33:44",
          "updated_at": "2018-12-25 09:33:44"
     }
    }
```

Но эта связь мне вообще не нужна в таком виде, как мне сделать что бы я мог получить следующее

```
   {
     "id": 1,
     "email": "imedhurst@example.org",
     "created_at": "2018-12-25 09:33:44",
     "updated_at": "2018-12-25 09:33:44",
     "name": "John Doe"
    }
```

Где name складывается из связей fistName && lastName

И я мог ее правильно подключать в контролере

Я не могу подключить связь которая возвращает строковое значение

Comment: а зачем вообще разбивать такие данные на разные таблицы?

Comment: Судя по наличию идентификатора языка - я бы предположил локализацию.

Comment: Вы не можете реализовать связь, которая будет возвращать строку. Связь возвращает модель.

Answer (score 0):

В модели `User` нужно написать getter для свойства `name`:

```
public function getNameAttribute() 
{
  return $this->first_name . ' ' . $this->last_name->title;
}
```

Comment: Я думаю, вы не совсем поняли вопрос

Comment: @Ипатьев почему же? Я ответил этим на все вопросы. Данный метод можно юзать в контроллере, name складывается из `first_name` и `last_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Всем

В общем нашел то что нужно

Кому интересно тут

[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gyr5ZMNaPbc)

[Почитать](https://hackernoon.com/reusable-api-resource-with-nested-relationship-laravel-5-5-c654c7243869)